# Why is the activated lifecycle hook not called on first visit

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I have a problem where a component within a `router-view` that is being kept alive does not call its `activated` lifecycle hook when first created. The `created` and `mounted` lifecycle hooks are being called. On a second visit, the `activated` hook is being called.

The scenario is quite complicated as there is a bit of nesting and slot using involved.

I've tried to create a minimal example which you can find below, or a bit more detailed on https://codesandbox.io/s/251k1pq9n.

Unfortunately, it is quite large and still not as complicated as the real code which I unfortunately cannot share.

Worse, I failed to reproduce the actual problem in my minimal example. Here, the `created`, `mounted`, and `activated` lifecycle hooks are all called when first visiting `SlotExample`.

In my real code, only the `created` and `mounted`, lifecycle hooks are called on the first visit, the `activated` hook is called on subsequent visits. Interestingly, all lifecycle hooks are called as expected for `SlotParent`.

The real code involves more nesting and makes use of slots to use layout components.

My code is using Vue 2.5.16 and Vue-Router 3.0.1 but it also doesn't work as expected in Due 2.6.7 and Vue-Router 3.0.2. I am also using Vuetify and Vue-Head but don't think think this has anything to do with my problem.

index.js.

Does anyone have an idea what I could have been doing wrong. I actually suspect a bug in vue-router 
when using multiple nested slots and `keep-alive` but cannot reproduce.

index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import App from "./App.vue";
import Start from "./Start.vue";
import SlotExample from "./SlotExample.vue";

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/start",
       component: Start
    },
    {
        path: "/slotExample/:id",
        component: SlotExample,
        props: true
    }
];

const router = new VueRouter({ routes });

Vue.use(VueRouter);

new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
    router,
    components: { App }
}).$mount("#app");
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <div>
            <keep-alive><router-view/></keep-alive>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

SlotExample.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Slot Example</h1>
        <router-link to="/start"><a>start</a></router-link>
        <router-link to="/slotExample/123">
    <a>slotExample 123</a>
  </router-link>
        <slot-parent :id="id">
            <slot-child
                slot-scope="user"
                :firstName="user.firstName"
                :lastName="user.lastName"/>
        </slot-parent>
    </div>  
</template>

<script>
    import SlotParent from "./SlotParent.vue";
    import SlotChild from "./SlotChild.vue";
    export default {
        name: "slotExample",
        components: { SlotParent, SlotChild },
        props: {
            id: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

SlotParent.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div slot="header"><h1>SlotParent</h1></div>
        <div slot="content-area">
            <slot :firstName="firstName" :lastName="lastName" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "slotParent",
        props: {
            id: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        },
        computed: {
            firstName() {
                if (this.id === "123") {
                    return "John";
                } else {
                    return "Jane";
                }
            },
            lastName() {
                return "Doe";
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

SlotChild.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>SlotChild</h2>
        <p>{{ firstName }} {{ lastName }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "slotChild",
        props: {
            firstName: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            lastName: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        },
        created() {
            console.log("slotChild created");
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log("slotChild mounted");
        },
        activated() {
            console.log("slotChild activated");
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put `SlotChild` within `keep-alive` block.

Take a look at [vue js doc about activated hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#activated)

Comment: Doing so breaks even my minimal example. SlotChild is not loaded at all anymore.